# How Do I Pull Maven Test Jars Using Gradle?

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, dependencies, gradle

In maven I can specify a "type"  for dependency resolution. I am trying to pull down a `tests.jar`. How can I do this using Gradle?

I have tried using the Gradle Dependency below, but this does not pull down `test.jar`.

```
testCompile(group: 'org.apache.hbase', name: 'hbase', version: '0.94.2', type: 'test-jar')
```

**Maven Dependency:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
    <version>0.94.2</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

***details:** Gradle 1.7*

*I am trying to pull down "hbase-0.94.2-tests.jar" from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.hbase|hbase|0.94.2|jar)*

Comment: `classifier: 'tests'` might work (instead of `type: ...`).

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser That does finally get me the jar I was looking for. I believe I had tried `classifier: 'test'` and `classifier: 'test-jar'` which did not work.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Gradle doesn't have a direct equivalent of Maven's `<type>`, but `classifier: 'tests'` should work here (instead of `type: ...`).

Comment: How did you know the classifier would be "tests" ?

Comment: @BeepDog If you look at how the artifacts are stored in the Maven repository, using a classifier of "tests" should become clear:

http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/2.2.0/

Answer (score 5):

use `classifier`, example:

```
    testImplementation("io.vertx:vertx-core") {
      artifact {
        classifier = 'tests'
      }
    }
    testImplementation("io.vertx:vertx-web") {
      artifact {
        classifier = 'tests'
      }
    }
```

Comment: Example is King 

Comment: Great example, useful when using BOMs

Answer (score -2):

Two modules in one Root project **demo-parent**

```
demo-parent
  |---demo-core
  |---demo-task
```

if you want to use some testCase common tools from **demo-core** in **demo-task**:

```
project(":demo-task") {
  dependencies {
    implementation(project(":demo-core"))
    
    testImplementation project(':demo-core').sourceSets.test.output
  }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure this unrelated to the question.