# How to use Neo4j test jars with gradle

Tags: neo4j, gradle

In a gradle project I'm trying to pull in the `org.neo4j.test` package so I can use `ImpermanentGraphDatabase` for testing. I ran into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224260/how-do-i-pull-maven-test-jars-using-gradle) which led me to declare my dependency like this:

```
testCompile group: 'org.neo4j', name: 'neo4j-kernel', version: '2.1.2', classifier: 'tests'
```

However, I don't see `org.neo4j.test` in my cache and it blows up when I try to run the test suite. For what it's worth, if I go into Intellij, it can sense that I don't have that class on my classpath and it fixes it just fine. What could I be missing in my build config? Thanks!

UPDATE:

Here is my dependency tree:

> --- org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:2.1.2
>        +--- org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:2.1.2
>        --- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:1.1.1

The weird thing is, it can't find the class when I try to build with Gradle - but when I open Intellij the helper window says :

> "Add library:'Gradle:neo4j-kernel-2.1.2-tests' to classpath"

And when I click on that everything is fine.

Comment: Could you give more details about: 'it blows up when I try to run the test suite.'? eg, stacktrace etc

Comment: Here is the error during compilation:  error: package org.neo4j.test does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In couple of gradle based projects I'm using exactly the same snippet with `classifier='tests'` - this works very well, see e.g. https://github.com/sarmbruster/neo4j-spock-extension/blob/master/build.gradle. (side note: this build uses `compile` scope instead of `testCompile` intentionally to export the dependencies).

Could you please paste the output of `gradle dependencies` for further insights.

Comment: which gradle version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.11

Comment: Once I blew away the cache and changed the dependency to compile scope everything started working. Still not totally sure why, but I'll elaborate once I spot it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your dependency without problem:

```
testCompile group: 'org.neo4j', name: 'neo4j-kernel', version: '2.1.2', classifier: 'tests'
```

Correct jar has been downloaded and used.

Could you please try:

```
gradle test --refesh-dependencies
```

Comment: No luck refreshing dependencies. I opened a brand new project with the `neo4j-kernel` being the only dependency and I'm still seeing the same issue.

Comment: my one was downloaded into {userhome}\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.6\descriptors\org.neo4j, maybe delete {userhome}\.gradle\caches and try again.

Comment: I blew away the caches but unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! Ultimately change the score to compile did the trick.