# How to depend on a test Maven jar in Bazel?

Tags: java, dependency-management, bazel

Some Maven artifacts in addition to the main jar provide a separate test jar which contains classes to aid with writing tests that use the dependency. [`kafka-streams`](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22kafka-streams%22) is one example. In Gradle it's possible to depend on such a jar using `classifier: "test"` (if the test jar has `-test.jar` suffix) and in Maven that would be `<type>test-jar</type>`. How to add a test jar to a Bazel workspace?

Comment: A question about the same functionality in Gradle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224260/how-do-i-pull-maven-test-jars-using-gradle#20225377

Comment: Can you write a separate `maven_jar` rule for the test one?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to figure out how to do :)

Comment: Note that the question is about the case when the same artifact provides both an ordinary and a test jar. Visit the link to Maven Central from the question for an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Skylark maven_jar implementation supports this, with the artifact syntax of `group:artifact:version:packaging:classifier`.

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:maven_rules.bzl", "maven_jar")
maven_jar(
    name = "org_apache_kafka_test",
    artifact = "org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:1.0.0:jar:test",
    sha1 = "b275b72148aad7a59cc12f1005507d61fc0ae77b",
)
```

Comment: Finally got to test it: works as advertised, thanks Adam. Is the Skylark rule something that's safe to use as a drop-in replacement or there're things to consider? E.g. why it's not the default?

Answer (score 1):

I think this feature is missing from `maven_jar`.

I could write a rule for the main jar:

```
maven_jar(
    name = "org_apache_kafka",
    artifact = "org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:1.0.0",
    sha1 = "a6c87c367176beb7650eb2df173fd9fe6e38656f",
)
```

But I could not write one for the test jar, this didn't work:

```
maven_jar(
    name = "org_apache_kafka_test",
    artifact = "org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:1.0.0-test",
    sha1 = "b275b72148aad7a59cc12f1005507d61fc0ae77b",
)
```

I recommend filing a feature request at https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/new .

Comment: I tried exactly what you suggest without luck too. Is there any point in filing an issue if the feature is supported by the Skylark rule as pointed out by Adam? As I understand Skylark will superceed the current generation of rules eventually or it's not true?

Comment: [raindev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057275/raindev), I'm glad it works! There's no point in filing a bug if the Skylark implementation works. Thanks!